# MySQL join tables with Kotlin Exposed error: "no matching primary/foreign key pair"

Tags: mysql, sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am working with a legacy MySQL database in Kotlin using the Exposed library. I've got it working fine with MySQL (simple queries work as expected). I'm running MySQL version 5.7.26, but I don't think the problem is related to MySQL itself.

I have two tables, events and event_years. The relevant columns in events are the id (int, primary key), and name (varchar 255). Event_years contains an id (int, primary key), year (datetime), and event_id (int, foreign key), among other things that are not relevant to this question.

An event may have zero or more rows in event_years referring to it. I would like to select the event name, and year, and order the results by year.

I was able to achieve this using the mysql CLI like this:

```sql
SELECT e.id, e.name, y.id, y.date 
FROM events e, event_years y
WHERE e.id = y.event_id
ORDER BY y.date;
```

In Kotlin, I have created objects for Events and EventYears:

```
object Events : Table("events") {
    val id = integer("id").autoIncrement().primaryKey()
    val name = varchar("name", length = 255)
}

object EventYears : Table("event_years") {
    val id = integer("id").autoIncrement().primaryKey()
    val eventId = integer("event_id").uniqueIndex()
    val date = date("date")
}
```

I have then tried the following query:

```
val res = EventYears.innerJoin(Events)
    .slice(Events.name, Events.id, EventYears.date, EventYears.id)
    .select { EventYears.eventId eq Events.id }
    .groupBy(EventYears.date)
```

I expected the result to be an Iterable object containing these values (like the ones I've received when doing queries without joining), but an exception was raised:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot join with foo.bar.Events@b307e119 as there is no matching primary key/ foreign key pair and constraint missing
```

Thank you in advance for any help. I've read the Exposed documentation twice now and still can not understand why this is not working.

Comment: That means you want to achieve years also if event not exist. Event may have zero columns but you want years and event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your `eventId` as `val eventId = reference("film", Events).uniqueIndex()` then you'll be possible to use your query without an exception.

The other way is to provide both columns explicitly in `innerJoin`

```
val res = EventYears.innerJoin(Events, {EventYears.eventId}, {Events.id})
    .slice(Events.name, Events.id, EventYears.date, EventYears.id)
    .selectAll()
    .groupBy(EventYears.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the constraint :

```
val joinResult = Events.join(EventYears, JoinType.INNER, additionalConstraint = {
EventYears.eventId eq Events.id
```

Then select as follows

```
joinResult.select({ EventYears.eventId eq Events.id }) {
   val eventId = it[Events.id]
   val eventYearsId = it[EventYears.eventId]
}
```